# What is my username in SVN

Tags: svn

I have a `WC` of an `SVN` repository. I checked it out a long time ago and I don't remember what was the `username` and `password` I used. Now, I want to check out the same repository on a different box and I fail to recall what `username/password` I should use.

Is there a way I can retrieve this information, or should I contact my administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made the last check in before you checked it out, try `svn info` when inside the dir or `svn info [filename]` or `svn log [filename]` on a file you know you edited.

Comment: In the output of `svn info` in the working copy I can see my username - is this the one used for the checking out as well? What about the password?

Comment: username is the one used at time of check-in, not out. password is a little harder (as in i know when you check out it usually asks if you want to store the password unencrypted on the system, but i've no idea where it dumps that. prolly somewhere in the .svn dir inside the working checkout dir).

Comment: after some poking about, try your home dir/subversion/auth/svn-simple/

Comment: I visited `svn.simple` but found nothing. In my second visit there, I realized that my password was saved in the keychain (I'm using MAC OS X). There I could find it! `svn info` helps, indeed, finding the username in use.

Comment: i guess it depends on the authentication type used (theres a few other dirs in the auth dir). On my system it was in svn.simple. Oh wells :)

Comment: Thanks anyway - your answer was not the direct one, the the hinting one :) As my goal was accomplished this is good as exact answer:)